# C# - Replace part of string from ListBox with RichTextbox Data

Tags: c#, string, listbox, replace, richtextbox

I have a listBox labeled `placementTwoListBox` where I have data loaded into it. The placementTwoListBox looks like this:

### `placementTwoListBox`:

```
U3      IC-00276G   236.135  198.644  90   
U12     IC-00270G   250.610  201.594  0    
J1      INT-00112G  269.665  179.894  180  
J2      INT-00112G  269.665  198.144  180  
J6      INT-00113G  227.905  174.994  180  
J3      INT-00113G  227.905  203.244  180  
U13     EXCLUDES    242.210  181.294  180
```

---

I also have **TWO** richTextBoxes labeled `calculatedXRichTextBox` and `calculatedYRichTextBox`. They look like this:

### `calculatedXRichTextBox`:

```
246.135
260.610
279.665
279.665
237.905
237.905
252.210
```

---

### `calculatedYRichTextBox`:

```
298.644
301.594
279.894
298.144
274.994
303.244
281.294
```

---

I am trying to replace the values in the ***3rd column*** of `placementTwoListBox` with the values in **`calculatedXRichTextBox`** and replace the values in the ***4th column*** of `placementTwoListBox` with the values in **`calculatedYRichTextBox`** to get the final result *(and placing it back into the original ListBox)* of:

### `placementTwoListBox` *(updated)*:

```
U3      IC-00276G   246.135  298.644  90   
U12     IC-00270G   260.610  301.594  0    
J1      INT-00112G  279.665  279.894  180  
J2      INT-00112G  279.665  298.144  180  
J6      INT-00113G  237.905  274.994  180  
J3      INT-00113G  237.905  303.244  180  
U13     EXCLUDES    252.210  281.294  180
```

---

- Does anyone know how to implement this?

### ***EDIT:***

**When using these two:**    @CrazyDart

`calculatedXRichTextBox`:

```
758.135
772.61
791.665
791.665
749.905
749.905
764.21
```

`calculatedYRichTextBox`:

```
-301.356
-298.406
-320.106
-301.856
-325.006
-296.756
-318.706
```

The `placementTwoListBox` turns out to look like this:

```
U3      IC-00276G   758.135  -301.356666666  90   
U12     IC-00270G    772.61  -298.40666666  0    
J1      INT-00112G  791.665  -320.1066666  180  
J2      INT-00112G  791.665  -301.856666  180  
J6      INT-00113G  749.905  -325.00666  180  
J3      INT-00113G  749.905  -296.7566  180  
U13     EXCLUDES     764.21  -318.706  180
```

Comment: Colton, does your professor know StackOverflow does all your homework for you?

Comment: @AresAvatar: I am not in school. I am trying to learn little things and I don't have a book. Thanks though..

Comment: @AresAvatar: Sorry. I have just been a little frustrated with people assuming I am in school or doing this for something like that. I am really just trying to learn and build something from scratch.

Comment: Colton, no worries. I was just giving you a nudge nudge wink wink, and I did not take offense at all to your replies. I hope you were not offended either.  BTW, +1 on your question.

Comment: @AresAvatar: Haha. No I am good.. it is a little hard to tell sarcasm through the computer.. :). Thanks for the +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
        string[] lines = placementTwoListBox.Lines;
        for (int line = 0; line < lines.Length; line++)
        {
            string replacement1 = calculatedXRichTextBox.Lines[line];
            while (replacement1.Length < 7)
            {
                replacement1 = " " + replacement1;
            }
            lines[line] = lines[line].Remove(20, 7).Insert(20, replacement1);

            string replacement2 = calculatedYRichTextBox.Lines[line];
            while (replacement2.Length < 7)
            {
                replacement2 = " " + replacement2;
            }
            lines[line] = lines[line].Remove(29, 7).Insert(29, replacement1);
        }
        placementTwoListBox.Lines = lines;
```

UPDATE:  I totally missed that some are lists, not all RichTextBoxes... see updated code:

```
    for (int line = 0; line < placementTwoListBox.Items.Count; line++)
    {
        string replacement1 = calculatedXRichTextBox.Lines[line];
        while (replacement1.Length < 7)
        {
            replacement1 = " " + replacement1;
        }
        placementTwoListBox.Items[line] = ((string)placementTwoListBox.Items[line]).Remove(20, 7).Insert(20, replacement1);

        string replacement2 = calculatedYRichTextBox.Lines[line];
        while (replacement2.Length < 7)
        {
            replacement2 = " " + replacement2;
        }
        placementTwoListBox.Items[line] = ((string)placementTwoListBox.Items[line]).Remove(29, 7).Insert(29, replacement1);
    }
```

Comment: hmmm, you might also want to trim the replacement string before the while loop...  string replacement1 = calculatedXRichTextBox.Lines[line].Trim();

Comment: `placementTwoListBox.Lines` does not work. There is no `.Lines` for placementTwoListBox.. So the first and last lines do not work properly

Comment: Should I use the `.Text.Split` instead of `.Lines`?

Comment: sorry, I missed that some of those are lists not all RichTextBoxes... I updated the code.

Comment: Tested it. It works for the most part, except on your last line it shold be `replacement2` not replacement1. However, I had a question about your code. When I test it it outputs the correct values *for the most part*. There seems to be an added digit in the decimal place. Some results I am getting look like this **`-51.3564`** when the *4* should not be there..

Comment: I think it has to do something with a fixed width when the data is not fixed.

Comment: well, at this point I can do all the work for you and fix the bugs or you can take the time to learn how to write c# and fix this your self.  My code was 100% for the first set of requirements... now the data has changed and its not going to work.  I would suggest you change the code to detect the beginning and end of the line, perhaps using indexOf or something.  Good luck... I want the points, but I am not going to do it all for you.

Answer (score 1):

This code is to fill the `calculatedXRichTextBox` and `calculatedYRichTextBox` from the `placementTwoListBox`:

```
string[] lines = new string[placementTwoListBox.Items.Count];

for (int itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < lines.Length; itemIndex++)
{ 
    lines[itemIndex] = placementTwoListBox.Items[itemIndex].ToString();
}

List<string> calculatedXLines = new List<string>();//to fill calculatedXRichTextBox
List<string> calculatedYLines = new List<string>();//to fill calculatedYRichTextBox

foreach (string line in lines)
{
    string[] items = line.Split(new string[] { "\t", " " }, 
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntires);

    if (items.Length > 2)
    {
        calculatedXLines.Add(items[2]);
        calculatedYLines.Add(items[3]);
    }
}

//add them to the calculatedYRichTextBox and the placementTwoListBox
calculatedXRichTextBox.Text = string.Join("\n", calculatedXLines); 
calculatedYRichTextBox.Text = string.Join("\n", calculatedYLines);
```

**Edit:** Answering the question:

```
string[] calculatedXLines = calculatedXRichTextBox.Text.Split(new string[] { "\n", "\r" },
```

StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

```
string[] calculatedYLines = calculatedYRichTextBox.Text.Split(new string[] { "\n", "\r" },
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

string[] lines = new string[placementTwoListBox.Items.Count];

for (int itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < lines.Length; itemIndex++)
{ 
    lines[itemIndex] = placementTwoListBox.Items[itemIndex].ToString();
}

List<string[]> newLines = new List<string[]>();

for (int lineIndex = 0; lineIndex < lines.Length; lineIndex++)
{
    string[] items = lines[lineIndex].Split(new string[] { " ", "\t" },
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    items[2] = calculatedXLines[lineIndex];
    items[3] = calculatedYLines[lineIndex];

    newLines.Add(items);
}

//represents your data on the `placementTwoListBox`:
placementTwoListBox.Items.Clear();
foreach (string[] lineItems in newLines)
{
    placementTwoListBox.Items.Add(string.Join("\t", lineItems));
}
```

Comment: we dont know that those are tabs... they are most likely spaces.

Comment: @Jalal: I am a little lost in your code. I don't understand how you can take the `placementTwoListBox.Text`. I think I need to grab each **`.Item`** in the list? Also, is this just for the `calculatedYRichTextBox`.. what would I change for the `calculatedXRichTextBox`? -- I am trying to take both of the RichTextBoxes and add/Replace them in the ListBox

Comment: @Colton: I miss understand your question. This code here is just take grab fill the  `calculatedXRichTextBox` and `calculatedYRichTextBox`. I read your question again now.. I will update the answer.

Comment: @Jalal: This does not seem to do anything. I am working with it and I will see if I can get it to work properly

Comment: @Jalal: I have extracted the ListBox into a new `RichTextBox`. So if it makes it easier to `Text.Split` the textbox up and replace the **3rd and 4th columns** in the `RichTextBox` with the values on each newline in the other two `RichTextBoxes`..?

Comment: @Colton: Sorry, I don't know why I was assuming that the `placementTwoListBox` is a `RichTextBox`, However I fixed the code. note also I replace the `Envirunment.NewLine` with a `"\n"` because I don't know how the items on the richTextBoxes are inserted "weather they inserted using `"\n"`"